# Conditional formatting cells between sheets and outputing to a seperate cell

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub MatchLiquor()

    Dim lastRowOne As Long
    Dim lastRowTwo As Long
    Dim sheetNameOne As String
    Dim sheetNameTwo As String

    sheetNameOne = "Recipies"             'Recipies Sheet
    sheetNameTwo = "Liquor Breakdowns"    'Liquor Breakdowns

    lastRowOne = Sheets(sheetNameOne).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowTwo = Sheets(sheetNameTwo).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For lRow = 2 To lastRowOne            'Loop through all rows

        For lRowTwo = 2 To lastRowTwo     'Loop through all rows

            If Sheets(sheetNameOne).Cells(lRow, "B") = Sheets(sheetNameTwo).Cells(lRowTwo, "A") Then
                Sheets(sheetNameOne).Cells(lRow, "C") * Sheets(sheetNameOne).Cells(lRowTwo, "E") Then

            End If

        Next lRowTwo

    Next lRow

End Sub
```

In sudo, what I'm attempting to accomplish is such:
Search through all rows of sheetA for "name" and compare to sheetB "name"
Upon being found, multiply different value in sheetA with different value in sheetB; output values into different cell in sheetA (example E).

I haven't yet figured out how to output, or even if this will work.
Ideas?

Comment: [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) × [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) or [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) × [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) would do. Why do you need VBA?

Comment: Call it a learning experience ... though I forgot the second string;  I've written enough of it now, not specific to this question, that not knowing "how" is eating at me.  If that makes sense?

Thank you for the correction(s).

Comment: OK, is this line's worksheet correct? `Sheets(sheetNameTwo).Cells(lRowTwo, "A")`. You defined `lRowTwo` in a For... next to `lastRowTwo`. `lastRowTwo ` was defined as the last row in `sheetNameOne` not `sheetNameTwo`.

Comment: It's not clear where you want to put the product of `Sheets(sheetNameOne).Cells(lRow, "C") * Sheets(sheetNameOne).Cells(lRowTwo, "E")`.

Comment: Yeah... I re-wrote it, instead of copy pasting and got ahead of myself.
lastRowTwo should be defined as SheetNameTwo; and before that sheetNameTwo should be declared as a string. Yes, it isn't clear ... because I do not know how to output it; which was part of the initial question; in addition if "it" would even work in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some confusion as to which worksheets were used where and no target for the product on a match was provided but this should clear up your loops.

```
Sub MatchLiquor()

    Dim lastRowOne As Long, lastRowTwo As Long, prodct As Double
    Dim sheetNameOne As String, sheetNameTwo As String

    sheetNameOne = "Recipies"             'Recipies Sheet
    sheetNameTwo = "Liquor Breakdowns"    'Liquor Breakdowns

    With Sheets(sheetNameOne)
        lastRowOne = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lastRowTwo = Sheets(sheetNameTwo).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For lRow = 2 To lastRowOne            'Loop through all rows on Recipies Sheet
            For lRowTwo = 2 To lastRowTwo     'Loop through all rows on Liquor Breakdowns

                If .Cells(lRow, "B") = Sheets(sheetNameTwo).Cells(lRowTwo, "A") Then
                    prodct = .Cells(lRow, "C").Value * Sheets(sheetNameTwo).Cells(lRowTwo, "E").Value
                    'do something with prodct
                    .cells(lRow, "E") = prodct
                    Exit For     'found match and computed product; no need to continue this lRowTwo
                End If

            Next lRowTwo
        Next lRow
    End With

End Sub
```

If a match was found and a product calculated (and put somewhere) there is no need to continue running through the internal nested loop with `lRowTwo`. Just `Exit For` which will take you back to the outside loop and the next `lRow`.

Using `Sheets(sheetNameOne)` in a [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) cuts down the parent worksheet references by half.

Comment: Output it where? To date you have provided no destination.

Comment: I meant generically (: but to be specific, sheetNameOne, E2; and thank you for all the insightful assistance!

Comment: Though this is to be repeated a large number of times; so, it would be Column E and onward, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you kindly ... the compiler didn't like any of my attempted solutions; in addition thank you for taking the time.